# Inheritance between 2 django classes

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance, django-views

I would like to inherite method from a first class to a second one separated in two different files. I'm getting a little issue according to arguments given in my method.

I have a file named : **main.py**

```
class CustomCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = '...'
    model = ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Update the context data with query_string.
        """
        context = super(CustomCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = _("Add new ") + str(self.model._meta.verbose_name)

        context['actual_page'] = get_actual_page(self.request)
        context['actual_search'] = get_actual_search(self.request)
        context['actual_sort'] = get_actual_sorting(self.request, self.default_sort_params[0])
        context['actual_pagination'] = get_pagination(mylist, self.pk)

        return context

def get_actual_page(request):
    actual_page = request.GET.get('page', None)
    ...
    return actual_page


def get_actual_sorting(request, default):
    actual_sorting = request.GET.get('sorting', default)
    return actual_sorting


def get_actual_search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    return q


def get_pagination(mylist, pk):
    actual_pagination = [mylist[x:x + settings.PAGE_LIMIT] for x in range(0, len(mylist), settings.PAGE_LIMIT)]
    ...
    return actual_pagination
```

And I have another file : **views.py**

```
class MyFormView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CustomCreateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        page_row_ids = self.request.session.get('result_recordset', [])

        my_pagination = context['actual_pagination']
        actual_pagination, first_page, last_page, page_number = my_pagination(page_row_ids, pk)
```

**Question:**

In my first file, How I can write arguments in `context['actual_pagination'] = get_pagination(mylist, self.pk)` in order to insert any list when I will call this one (e.g `page_row_ids`)?

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

I created a function in main.py file :

```
def get_pagination(mylist, pk)
```

This function takes 2 arguments :

- `myList`: generic argument which have to be replaced by a `list`
- `pk`: generic argument which have to be replaced by an `id`

I call this function in my `get_context_data()` method located in my `CustomCreateView` class.

Now I have another class (in a second file) which inherite from `CustomCreateView`. And I would like to call my method `get_pagination` by replacing `myList` argument by `page_row_ids` and `pk` by `pk`.

So in my child class, I would like to get :

```
context['actual_pagination'] = my_pagination(myList=page_row_ids, pk=pk)
actual_pagination, first_page, last_page, page_number = my_pagination(myList=page_row_ids, pk=pk)
```

> File "/home/Bureau/Projets/my_project/src/app/views.py" in
>   get_context_data
>     872.         context = super(MyFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
>
> File "/home/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/3.6.2/src/app/main.py" in
>   get_context_data
>     50.         context['actual_pagination'] = get_pagination(myList, self.pk)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /slug/edit/41 Exception Value:
>   'MyFormView' object has no attribute 'myList'

How I can do that ? Hopfully it's more clearable with my edit

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What arguments? What list? What do you want the result to be?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited my question ;)

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure I understand your question, but the normal way to do things like this would be to override `get_pagination` in your child class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's exactly what I would like to do. But I don't overcome to write `get_pagination` correctly. Because I have issue with arguments given in `CustomCreateView`. I edit my question with Traceback in 30s.